# Converting the coordinate system of x, y of shapes in an image to latitudes and longitudes

Tags: python, coordinate-system, convert, opencv

I have screenshots from Google Maps that show the traffic condition in Tehran (6000*4000 pixels):
[image]

I have extracted the red sections using Opencv and then drawn these sections as lines in a new shapefile using the following code:

```
def cnt_to_sh(directory, save_directory, file_name, rgb_min, rgb_max, color):

    orginal_img = os.path.join(directory, file_name)

    # Read the image file
    img = cv.imread(orginal_img)


    # Check if image file exists and path is correct
    # if not os.path.exists(img):
    #     print("Image file not found or path is incorrect")
    #     exit()

    # Create a new shapefile with lines as the geometry type
    w = shapefile.Writer(save_directory + f'/{file_name[:-4]}_'+ color +'.shp', shapeType=shapefile.POLYLINE)

    # Create fields for the shapefile attributes
    w.field('ID', 'N')

    # Define RGB min and max values for red-amber color range
    rgb_min_red_amber = rgb_min
    rgb_max_red_amber = rgb_max

    # Convert image from BGR to HSV color space
    hsv_img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # Extract pixels within specified color range
    fiber = cv.inRange(hsv_img, rgb_min, rgb_max)

    # Skeletonize the extracted pixels
    fiber_skel = pcv.morphology.skeletonize(fiber)

    # Extract contours from skeletonized image
    contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(fiber_skel, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    #get only contours of fibers (which usually will be greater than 200)
    # fiber_contours = [c for c in contours if cv.arcLength(c, False) > 10]
    # Check if any contours were extracted
    if len(contours) == 0:
        print("No contours were extracted from the image")
        exit()

    # Iterate over the contours and add them as lines to the shapefile
    for i, cnt in enumerate(contours):
        # Remove single-dimensional entries from contour array
        cnt = cnt.reshape(1, -1, 2)

        # Add contour to shapefile as a line
        w.line(cnt.tolist())

        # Record ID of contour in shapefile
        w.record(i)

    # Save the shapefile
    w.close()
```

The found red sections:
[image]

The problem is that the shapefiles made here are not drawn in the desired scale, and I cannot merge them with the main shapefile I have for Tehran, which is in this project format:

```
PROJCS["WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_39N",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",51.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

For georeferencing, I put the screenshot on top of my main shapefile of the city and wrote down the four corners of the image:

```
upper-left: 510850.11, 3966195.0
lower-left: 510959.95011, 3935297.77119
upper-right: 557432.77972, 3966357.58349
lower-right: 557540.61, 3935460.45
```

I am new to GIS and similar questions about pixel to longitude latitude conversions did not help. Is there any way I can convert my found red sections so that they align with the network I have in the main shapefile?

Comment: This is great work so far.   If you want to convert it programmatically with python you can use pyproj.  If you just want to export the shape file using QGIS or ArcGIS, you can right click the layer and "Export" the layer using Coordiante Reference System EPSG:4326 (longitude, latitude).  https://epsg.io .    If you use pyproj it looks like you are going from epsg 2059 to epsg 4326.  https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/examples.html#transformations-from-crs-to-crs